# modify html output of htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

When latex figures are converted to html, htlatex generates markup as follows:

```
 <a id="x3-3021r4"></a> 
 <p class="noindent" >
 <img src="sampleImage.png" alt="PIC"/>
 </p>
 <div class="caption">
    <span class="id">Abbildung&#x00A0;7:</span>
    <span class="content">Sample Image</span>
 </div>
```

Is it possible, e.g. through hooks and parameters in the config file, to change the output in such a way, that the resulting markup code looks like below?

```
<a id="x3-3021r4" href="/sampleImage.png" title="Sample Image"> 
   <img src="/sampleImage.png" alt="PIC"/>
</a>
</p>
<div class="caption">
  <span class="id">Abbildung&#x00A0;7:</span>
  <span class="content">Sample Image</span>
</div>
```

Regards, 
Chris

Edit: Added an MWE and modified needed output (anchor should also contain a 'title' attribute with the caption's content and the image path should be relative with a leading slash)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{sampleImage.png}
\caption{My sample image}
\label{fig:mysampleimage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The code is compiled with:

```
htlatex.bat src.tex "html"
```

Comment: could you please make MWE?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've edited the post. Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is more complex than it seems. It seems that label in inserted by `figure` environment, but I was not able to find how to configure it in the way you want. In this case I would recommend to use [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) filter functionality. `make4ht` is simple build tool which simplify use of `tex4ht`.

Filters are lua functions that modify the output. In your case, it could be such make file, `src.mk4`:

```lua
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local atoim = function(s)
  local id = nil
  return s:gsub("<([%a/]+)(%s*)([^>]-)>", function(tag, space, par)
    if tag == "a" then 
      id = par:match("^id=[\"']([^\"^']+)[\"']")
      if id then return '' end
    elseif tag=='/a' and id then
       return ''
    elseif id then
      par = 'id="'..id..'"'
      id = nil
    end 
    return '<'..tag ..space .. par..'>'
  end
  )
end
local process = filter{"cleanspan", "fixligatures", "hruletohr", atoim}
Make:htlatex()
Make:htlatex()
Make:match("html$",process)
```

now you can compile your document with

```
make4ht src
```

all tags are processed with `atoim` function, `<a id="something"></a>` are discarded and `id` value is saved, the `id` is then inserted in a following element.

Generated html then looks like:

```html
<!--l. 10--><p id="x1-21"><img 
src="sampleImage.png" alt="PIC"  
 />
<br /> </p>
```

note that `id` attribute can be put on any element and it will provide target for hyperlinks, it is not necessary to use `<a id`.

---

**edit**

for your use case, more complicated function must be used. maybe someone with knowledge of `xslt`  would find more elegant solution :-).

```lua
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local atoim = function(s)
  local id = nil
  local used_id = {}
  local captions = {}
  local tag_patt = "<([%a/]+)(%s*)([^>]-)>"
  local attr_pat = "%s*=%s*[\"']([^\"^']+)[\"']"
  s:gsub('<span class="content">(.-)</span></div><%!%-%-tex4ht%:label%?: (.-) %-%->', function(caption,id)
   captions[id]=caption
  end)
  local r1 =  s:gsub(tag_patt, function(tag, space, par)
    if tag == "a" then 
      id = par:match("^id"..attr_pat)--=[\"']([^\"^']+)[\"']")
    elseif id and tag == "img" then
      used_id[id] = true
      local src = par:match("src"..attr_pat) 
      local name = captions[id] or ""
      local img =  string.format('<a href="%s" id="%s" title="%s"><img %s></a>', src, id, name, par)
      id = nil
      return img
    end 
    return '<'..tag ..space .. par..'>'
  end
  )
  local a = false
  return r1:gsub(tag_patt, function(tag, space, par)
    if tag == "a" then
      local id = par:match("id"..attr_pat)
      if id and used_id[id] then
        used_id[id] = nil
        a = true
        return ""
      end
    elseif tag == "/a" and a then
      a = false
      return ""
    end
    return '<'..tag ..space .. par..'>'
  end
  )
end
local process = filter{"cleanspan", "fixligatures", "hruletohr", atoim}
Make:htlatex()
Make:htlatex()
Make:match("html$",process)
```

Three pass method is used, in first pass we find captions for given id, in the second pass label `id` and create `<a>` element around img, in the last pass, we remove old `<a>` element

Generated html:

```html
<!--l. 9--><p class="noindent" ><a href="sampleImage.png" id="x1-21" title="My sample image"><img src="sampleImage.png" alt="PIC"  
 /></a>
<br /> </p>
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your effort, I really appreciate it. The problem with this output is - and I'm sorry for not mentioning it before - that I want to use jQuery's fencybox [link](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) with the generated code. This plugin requires images to be in the format `<a id="imageId" href="imagelocation" title="imageName"><img src="imagelocation"/></a>` and will otherwise not work. But I will try to understand the lua function of your .mk4 file and change it according to my requirements.

Comment: @user46726 I think I have found the solution. It is little bit complex, I hope it will work for you

Comment: Wow, awesome! Thank you very much for your help. Best regards, Chris

Comment: @user46726 you are welcome. it was interesting exercise in what could be done with filters